# Problems of migration from dry package to wet package

Tags: pcl, catkin, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I met a problem  of migration from dry package (rosbuild) to wet package(catkin)..I'd like to know 2 things..

1 - The problems are about the .h files come from msg files.

I did:

```
add_message_files(
  FILES
    Message1.msg
    Message2.msg
)
generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
     std_msgs
 )
catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
    message_runtime
)
```

and in package.xml add dependency too..need i add some things like Include_library(xx)?
the .h files is in a directory named "msg_gen" some thing like a generation directory...

2 - How to use pcl package in dry package:
Because i want use pcl in a ROS dry package, but i found only the indice of configuration for wet packages. So i tied to migration dry package to wet package.

Thank you for help....

New :

I adjust most of my problems with your help, but there is always a problem rest..this is part of my CMakeList.txt

```
     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    message_generation
      pcl_ros
      roscpp
      rospy
       std_msgs 
       tf 
       sensor_msgs 
      geometry_msgs 
       nav_msgs 
       std_srvs 
    )
    find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
    
    add_message_files(FILES 
    aaa.msg
    bbb.msg
    ccc.msg
ddd.msg
    )
     add_service_files(FILES
     Test.srv
    BaseStop.srv
    ttt.srv
     )
     generate_messages(
       DEPENDENCIES
       std_msgs
    sensor_msgs  
     )
    catkin_package(
      CATKIN_DEPENDS
    message_runtime
     pcl_ros
     roscpp
      rospy
       std_msgs 
       tf 
       sensor_msgs 
      geometry_msgs 
       nav_msgs 
       std_srvs 
      DEPENDS system_lib 
    )
    
    include_directories(
      ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} include
    )
    
    add_library(libdxl src/dynamixel_sdk/src/dxl_hal.c)
    add_library(dynamixel src/dynamixel_sdk/src/dynamixel.c)
    target_link_libraries(dynamixel libdxl)
    
    
    add_library(ardu_instructions_lib src/driver/ardu_instructions.cpp)
    add_library(duino_driver_lib src/driver/duino_driver.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(duino_driver_lib ardu_instructions_lib)
    
    add_library(servos_lib src/servos.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(servos_lib dynamixel libdxl)
    
    add_library(base_controller_lib src/controllers/base_controller.cpp)
    add_library(aaa_controller_lib src/controllers/battery_controller.cpp)
    add_library(bbb_controller_lib src/controllers/joint_controller.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(bbb_controller_lib servos_lib)
    add_library(ccc_controller_lib src/controllers/ccc_controller.cpp)
    add_library(ddd_controller_lib src/controllers/ddd_controller.cpp)
    
    add_executable(ardu  src/ardu.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(ardu  duino_driver_lib base_controller_lib aaa_controller_lib bbb_controller_lib ccc_controller_lib ddd_controller_lib  pthread dynamixel libdxl ${catkin_LIBRARIES}${PCL_LIBRARIES})
    
    add_dependencies(libdxl ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
    add_dependencies(dynamixel ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
    add_dependencies(ardu_instructions_lib ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
    add_dependencies(duino_driver_lib ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
    add_dependencies(servos_lib ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
    add_dependencies(base_controller_lib ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
    add_dependencies(aaa_controller_lib ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
    add_dependencies(bbb_controller_lib ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
    add_dependencies(ccc_controller_lib ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
    add_dependencies(ddd_controller_lib ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
    add_dependencies(ardu ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

and part of my package.xml:

```
.....................
  <build_depend>pcl_ros</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pcl_msg</build_depend>
      <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
      <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
    <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
    <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
    <build_depend>tf</build_depend>
    <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
    <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
    <build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend>
    <build_depend>std_srvs</build_depend>
     <build_depend>libpcl-all-dev</build_depend>
      <!-- <build_depend version_gte="1.7.0">pcl</build_depend>-->

      <!--<run_depend version_gte="1.7.0">pcl</run_depend>-->
     <run_depend>libpcl-all</run_depend>
      <run_depend>std_srvs</run_depend>
      <run_depend>nav_msgs</run_depend>
      <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
      <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
      <run_depend>tf</run_depend>
      <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
      <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
    <run_depend>pcl_ros</run_depend>
 <run_depend>pcl_msg</run_depend>
      <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
    <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
```

The system can't find always the     BaseStop.h..but it can find the aaa.h or ddd.h in the same condition.. I'm so confused..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173249/problems-of-migration-from-dry-package-to-wet-package/) by [loulou0219](https://answers.ros.org/users/2562/loulou0219/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-06-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-06-10**:
For question 2, you should be able to use PCL from a dry package. If you want to do that, please open a new question, providing information about what you did and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with @gvdhoom that pending a better description of your exact error, the likely problem is one or more missing `add_dependencies()` commands for various build targets.

Additional documentation related to this question:

- http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/cpp_msg_dependencies.html
- http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/building_msgs.html

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> need i add some things like Include_library(xx)? the .h files is in a directory named "msg_gen" some thing like a generation directory...

Regarding issue 1: you don't give any specific errors you are encountering, but no, the message headers are *header only*, so no linking is required.

I suspect you are getting errors telling you that your generated headers cannot be found when compiling the nodes that include them: if that is the case, then you are missing a `add_dependencies(TARGET dep)`, where `dep` is the message generation target for a specific language (or all of them). Example (with the messages in the same package as the node that uses them):

```
add_dependencies(foo foo_generate_messages_cpp)
```

See also:

- [catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild#Migration_checks): Migration checks, bullet 10.
- [catkin_make started failing to generate .h from .msg](http://answers.ros.org/question/62092/catkin_make-started-failing-to-generate-h-from-msg/)
- [How to specify dependencies with "foo_msgs" catkin packages](http://answers.ros.org/question/52744/how-to-specify-dependencies-with-foo_msgs-catkin-packages/)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-06-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1